# popToRootViewControllerAnimated not releases the memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, memory-management, uinavigationcontroller

My app is ARC enabled and take approximate `19 Mb` when rootViewController loaded. From this screen when I push to next view controller using below code it take total approximate `41 Mb`

```
LoginViewController *loginNib=[[LoginViewController alloc] init];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:loginNib animated:YES];
```

From this `LoginViewController` when I come back to previous screen using below code Xcode memory indicator still showing `41 Mb`. ARC not releasing the memory.

```
[[self navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

But the surprising thing is then if I do the same again it's not increases the memory. Indicator showing `41 Mb`. for all the case. My all the outlet are connected via `weak pointer` even before calling `popToRootViewController` I have set all the `outlet to nil` but no progress.

I want to free those memory. Can anybody suggest me why ARC not releasing the consumed memory even after calling `popToRootViewController`.

Comment: Use Memory Leaks Instrument to check for memory leaks: http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode

Comment: the iOS deallocates an object whenever it wants or feels necessary to do so; you need to worry about not to keep an object alive by a `strong` reference accidentally and you have done everything you should have.